# Perl doesn't go to error section

Tags: perl, error-handling, die

I have a Perl statement like the one below

```
seek DCMFReport.txt, $offset, 0 or die "Report seek error, offset:$offset - $!";
```

When it hits the above line, I get an "argument error" but I don't see the text in the die printed out. I expected to see the "Report seek error..." printed out. Does that mean the code did not go to the die section even though the statement threw an error?

Comment: The way you have your code, it will try to call a function `DCMFReport()` and a function `txt()` and concatenate the return values of both, then use that value as the first argument to `seek`. Always `use strict` and `use warnings`!

Comment: that worked. what did the quotes add to that line if i may ask. thanks.

Comment: i do have use strict and use warnings

Comment: That shouldn't have worked... `seek` expects a filehandle as its first argument.

Comment: that did work, now the die is getting executed and i see the "Report seek..."

Comment: when i try seek $filename, $offset, 0 or die "Report seek error, offset:$offset - $!";  - it doesnt work either. It works if i put "$filename" in quotes

Answer (score 5):

Because [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) expects a file handle you need to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the file first. The file name is not the same as a file handle.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $offset = 1;

open my $fh, '<', 'DCMFReport.txt' or die $!;
seek $fh, $offset, 0 or die "Report seek error, offset:$offset - $!";
```

---

It will give you the `or die` error message if you use a string as the first argument, because the `seek` operation fails as the value is not a file handle. That's something else as passing something that does not exist.

The documentation says:

> FILEHANDLE may be an expression whose value gives the name of the filehandle.

A string is an expression, so it tries to operate on a file handle with that name.

Comment: @st well that's definitely better than bare wording it;-)

Comment: That didn't work though,                                                                                                                    I tried open                                                                                                       my $file, '<', $filename or die $!;

Comment: That didn't work though,                                                                                                                    I tried open  my $file, '<', $filename or die $!; followed by the seek   seek $file, $offset, 0 or die "Report...   - this doesn't go to the die, actually the problem was the offset, it was a non numeric value that was coming in. If i pass a numeric value in the offset, the script runs fine. If passed a non-numeric, the error doesn't go to the die, the entire script gets executed. Only time this works is if i put a quote around the file name in the seek

Comment: or rather a quote around the file handle as you mentioned. This works seek "$file", $offset, 0 or die "Report...  - even though i have the open my $file as a previous statement and open the file and then pass that FH to the next seek command as you mentioned, it only works when i put a quote around the FH. I am confused.

Comment: @md1980 I showed code here that compiles, and will catch runtime errors. Usually one would want the code to work and only catch runtime errors _if they occur_. If you actually **want to force a runtime error**, you still need _working_ code. Since your code was *not even working*, I fixed that. Now why do you want _the operation to fail_? Do you want to test whether the `or die` part works correctly? Are you writing a unit test? Give more details what what you need please.